# Cannot access Ubuntu Core ~/.bashrc

Tags: ubuntu-core, raspberrypi

I've installed Ubunt Core 16.04 on Raspberry Pi 3 (armv7). I've also installed python package using snap, but unfotunately I can't run it out of the box. The executable file of the snap package not installed to default bin PATH, so I should export this path :

```
/snap/python36-jamesh/23/bin
```

The problem is, I can't edit the ~/.bashrc using pre-installed nano. It said that permission denied. What I can do about it?

[Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEfCP.png)

[Permission Denied Warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yr1rj.png)

Comment: Post the exact command you ran and the exact error message. You can [edit] your post.

Comment: please open the image link